# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread when calling JSF Bean

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a problem with my small web application, when I'am calling 
 `<h:outputText value ="#{loginBeanService.getPerson()}"></h:outputText>`

I am getting such error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke 
    Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/serwis-
    ogloszeniowy] threw exception [Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread] with root cause
     org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:692)
        at pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.dao.PersonDao.findAll(PersonDao.java:40)
        at pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.dao.PersonDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e879d2a0.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at           org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
        at pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.dao.PersonDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e9a2ef0.findAll(<generated>)
        at pl.kosiaks.Serwis.core.LoginBeanService.getPerson(LoginBeanService.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:165)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:84)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

LoginBeanService.java:

```
package pl.kosiaks.Serwis.core;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.dao.PersonDao;
import pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.entity.Person;

@Service
@ManagedBean(name="loginBeanService")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBeanService {

@Autowired
private PersonDao personDao;



    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return this.personDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

PersonDao.java:

```
    package pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.entity.Person;

    @Repository
    public class PersonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    public void persist(Person entity) {
        this.sf.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    public void update(Person entity) {
        this.sf.getCurrentSession().update(entity);
    }

    public Person findById(String id) {
        Person Person = (Person) this.sf.getCurrentSession().get(Person.class, id);
        return Person; 
    }

    public void delete(Person entity) {
        this.sf.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        List<Person> persons = (List<Person>)    this.sf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Person").list();
        return persons;
    }

}
```

PersistenceConfig.java:

```
package pl.kosiaks.Serwis.spring;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-oracle.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.entity" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        final HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

PersistenceXmlConfig:

```
package pl.kosiaks.Serwis.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.dao", "pl.kosiaks.Serwis.core"})
@ImportResource({ "classpath:hibernate4Config.xml" })
public class PersistenceXmlConfig {

    public PersistenceXmlConfig() {
        super();
    }

}
```

hibernate4Config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:persistence-oracle.properties" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.kosiaks.Serwis.model.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.kosiaks.SerwisOgloszeniowy</groupId>
    <artifactId>serwis-ogloszeniowy</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>serwis-ogloszeniowy Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Unit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.42</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>serwis-ogloszeniowy</finalName>

    </build>
</project>
```

persistence-oracle.properties:

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXXX
jdbc.user=XXXX
jdbc.pass=XXXX

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of posting your full application, try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+obtain+transaction-synchronized+Session+for+current+thread&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Szymon-Kosiak You may want to try placing `@Transactional` annotation on the Repository

Comment: thanks it worked for me.